# Java counting array objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, counting

I have some questions regarding arrays in java:

How many objects are created in the following expressions?

(a) `new int[0]` : There is one object created, an array of size 0.???

(b) `new int[2][2]` : There is one object created, an array with 2 rows and columns.???

(c) `new int[2][]` : There is no object created???

I was wondering if my solutions next to the expressions are correct. If not, hopefuly you can help and give me some explanation about them. I don't really get what im supposed to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like an exam question. _"I'm not quite sure about the meaning of this question"_??

Comment: a) One object b) 3 objects c) 1 object

Comment: Now I've read it further it probably hardly belongs here much more than meta where you posted it a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**new int[0]**

Yes this is an empty array, one object is created.

```
    int[] emptyArray = new int[0];
    System.out.println(emptyArray.length); // Outputs 0
```

**new int[2][2]**

Yes this creates and array with 2 rows and columns, 3 objects are created.

```
    int[][] bar = new int[2][2];
    System.out.println(bar.getClass()); // Outputs class [[I
    int[] bar1 = bar[0];
    System.out.println(bar1.getClass());  // Outputs class [I
    int[] bar2 = bar[1];
    System.out.println(bar2.getClass());  // Outputs class [I
```

**new int[2][]**

Java supports jagged arrays.  This means when you create `int[2][]` this means you have an array of various sized `int[]`.  Only 1 object is created here.

```
    int[][] foo = new int[2][];
    System.out.println(foo[0]);  // Outputs null
    System.out.println(foo[1]);  // Outputs null
    foo[0] = new int[10];
    foo[1] = new int[5];
```

Comment: I understand what you did, but how many "objects" are created?. I mean  if you just code int[][] foo = new int[2][]; there won't be any object right? Because the empty[][] has to be filled first?

Comment: I believe `new int[2][]` creates one object only, which is the array object itself. I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, I think Eng.Found is correct. Only one object in each and every situation because the user is adding data types. But, multiple MEMORY LOCATIONS will be allocated

Comment: @user1923369 - I have updated my answer to include how many objects are created.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan: I don't think lot of objects will be created in any of the above arrays, instead the array object. because there is no 'new' keyword. Multiple memory locations will be created and they will be filled with data types, but can we call them as objects?

Comment: I now understand a) and b) but still a bit confused about c). In c) there is just one object created because the second,empty [] is filled with nothing and thus there will be no extra arrays created?

Comment: @Sepala - Check out my update to new `int[2][2]` there are definitely 3 instances that can be worked with as a result of one new call.

Comment: @user1923369 - Yes for c) there is just one object created.  You can populate the items in the outer array with instances of int[].

Answer (score 4):

The following is an excerpt from the Java Specification:

> In the Java programming language arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
>   dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
>   (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

This means every array is an own object, which makes your answer **a)** correct.

**b)** 3 objects are created: 1 array first and two arrays containing each 2 `int`s. I wouldn't count the `int`-entries as they are primitive types in Java.

**c)** 1 object is created: 1 array with two null-entries.